# Visual basic multiple handle events

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a question, how to create multiple handels for my code. I found some examples, but still don't know how to combine with my code. (I am total beginner, so any help or advise would be very helpful)

Here is what I like to create:

```
Private Sub t_VDOSC_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles t_VDOSC.LostFocus, t_VDOCC.LostFocus, t_VSOCC.LostFocus, t_VSOSC.LostFocus

        Dim not_ok As Boolean = False
        If IsNumeric(t_VDOSC.Text) = True Then
            If (CDbl(t_VDOSC.Text) >= 0 And CDbl(t_VDOSC.Text) <= 2.0) Or CDbl(t_VDOSC.Text) = 99999 Then

            Else
                not_ok = True
            End If
        Else
            not_ok = True
        End If

        If not_ok = True Then
            MsgBox("Values must be between 0 and 2!")
            t_VDOSC.Focus()
        End If
        text_default(sender)
    End Sub
```

In this code the second, third and fourth handles doesn't work. I can write manualy every handles by itself, but i think that this king of coding cold be faster and better for reviewing and managing.

For easiest code multiple handels work fine, but I dont't know how to manage with my, where I have some conditions.

Multiple handles that works for me:

```
Private Sub t_VDOSC_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles t_VDOSC.GotFocus, t_VDOCC.GotFocus, t_VSOCC.GotFocus, t_VSOSC.GotFocus
        text_aktive(sender)
    End Sub
```

`text_aktive` and `text_default` is color settings.

I found example in VB6, verey simple code, bit it has indexes, which I don't like to have in my code.

```
IF Index = 1 Or Index = 2, or Index = 6, or Index = 7 Then
If Text3(Index) >=0 And Text3(Index) <=4 Then
```

Is there any better solution for my code? I have a lot of TextBoxes and I would like to have it simple and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** You can handle multiple events in one handler as you mentioned. But the problem is that you are only using `t_VDOSC`, the first TextBox, so that, it seems second, third and forth are not working. You should use `sender` instead of `t_VDOSC`, the first TextBox.

**(2)** And you are checking validation in the `LostFocus` event; if the value is invalid you display the `MessageBox` and you set the focus back. This is the problem.

Let's say - ***TextBox A*** lost focus, then ***TextBox B*** got focus; 
you check the validation in ***TextBox A***'s `LostFocus` event, and then you set focus back to ***TextBox A***; it will fire the ***TextBox B*** `LostFocus` event again, and you set focus back to ***TextBox B*** again; (it will create a infinite loop).
To avoid the infinite loop, you can use `Validating` event.

**(3)** The solution is ... Let `LostFocus` event handler be like this

```
Private Sub t_VDOSC_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _ 
    t_VDOSC.LostFocus, t_VDOCC.LostFocus, t_VSOCC.LostFocus, t_VSOSC.LostFocus

    text_default(sender)
End Sub
```

**(4)** Check the data validation process in `Validating` event like this

```
Private Sub t_VDOSC_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
Handles t_VDOSC.Validating, t_VDOCC.Validating, t_VSOCC.Validating, t_VSOSC.Validating
    Dim t_sender As TextBox
    t_sender = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim not_ok As Boolean = False
    If IsNumeric(t_sender.Text) = True Then
        If (CDbl(t_sender.Text) >= 0 And CDbl(t_sender.Text) <= 2.0) Or CDbl(t_sender.Text) = 99999 Then

        Else
            not_ok = True
        End If
    Else
        not_ok = True
    End If

    If not_ok = True Then
                           'You don't need to call t_sender.Focus() here
        e.Cancel = True    'This will prevent losing focus with invalid data
        MsgBox("Values must be between 0 and 2!")
    End If
    text_default(t_sender)
End Sub
```

Reference: [Validating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Tis works great. I have another question. Is possible to have 2 `TextBoxes` with same name in 2 different tabs (I have `TabControl1` -> `TabPage1` and `TabPage2`), or I have to rename it differently (this is how I did now; I have changed name the `TextBox` in tab2, like `t_2_VDOSC`).

Comment: no, you cant set same name to different objects in `VB .NET`, but you can do it in `VB 6`